# Android - NumberFormatException - For input String

Tags: android, numberformatexception

I am saving data in my firebase database and I want to display it. This works but I get an exception when I say textview.setText("Bla " + object); The exception happens because of the result1 and result2 variable, but I don't know how to solve this problem. It happens in the setBias method.

```
public static class BetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView bias, foodEp, profit;
    View resultColor;
    double result1;
    double result2;
    double result;

    public BetViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        bias= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bias);
        foodEp= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food);
        profit= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profit);
    }

    public void setBias(String biasFoll) {
        bias.setText("Bias: " + biasFoll);
        result1 = Double.parseDouble(bias.getText().toString());
    }

    public void setFoodEp(String foodEpsa) {
        foodEp.setText(foodEpsa);
        result2 = Double.parseDouble(foodEp.getText().toString());
        result = result1 * result2;
        profit.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }
```

Comment: can you post your logcat error here?

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "bias 88"

Comment: did you know java? how could you parse string `bias 88` to double

Comment: check Potapov answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 ideas:

1) Mb you should change `result1 = Double.parseDouble(bias.getText().toString());` with `result1 = Double.parseDouble(biasFoll);`?

2) Surround your "result1 = Double.parseDouble(bias.getText().toString());" with `try {} catch (NumberFormatException e) {}` and set some default value to `result1`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert String to Double:

```
bias.setText("Bias: " + biasFoll);
result1 = Double.parseDouble(bias.getText().toString());
```

That is not possible and that's why you are getting `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Yes I know, how can I get around it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: I want to save the value of bias in result1 and value of foodEp in result2 inorder to multiply the values and display the on a textview. I thought I could do it this way, but this prevents me from writing any predifined text ("Bias: ") in my textview

Comment: If the value of `bias` and `foodEp` are any number format like `integer` or `double`, you can save that in `double` and multiply them. Try this: `result1 = Double.parseDouble(biasFoll);` This will work if the value of `biasFoll` is number type.

Answer (score 1):

use the following

Remeber that your string must consist a numeric value

```
bias.setText( biasFoll);

result1 = Double.parseDouble(bias.getText().toString().trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parse string `bias 88` to double, I have made some changes in your method look into it and try

```
 public void setBias(String biasFoll) {
     bias.setText("Bias: " + biasFoll);
     result1 = Double.parseDouble(biasFoll);
 }
```